# Uipath studio Data scraping takes forever

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

When my rpa start the data scraping, the rpa is able to start running but takes forever and never complete the data scraping. There is no error message output, the rpa never end. Why this is happening? And I strongly suspect it is caused by the selector.

[image: Data Scraping]

Selector of "Attach Browser 'Cookingoi' Page":

```
<html app='chrome.exe' htmlwindowname='nameStorage:?wm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fredmart.lazada.sg%2F%23home&amp;refer_pv_id=*' title='* - Buy * at Best Price in Singapore | www.lazada.sg' />
```

Selector of "Extract Structured Data 'DIV'":

```
<webctrl css-selector='body&gt;div&gt;div&gt;div&gt;div&gt;div' parentid='root' tag='DIV' />
```

Selector of "NextLinkSelector":

```
<webctrl idx='7' isleaf='1' parentid='root' tag='A' />
```

Comment: Are you using the "Next page" feature? Or just feating the page that you currently see?

Comment: try property wait for ready to complete

Comment: Yes, I am using the "Next page" feature. I had now placed the selector of "NextLinkSelector" on this question.

Comment: Yes, I ensured the properties of "Extract Structured Data 'DIV'" is ```WaitForReady.COMPLETE```
However, it is not working also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to do this you have to select the larger box encompassing the whole div for an item.
This is how my extract metadata tag looks like.

```
<extract>
    <row exact='1'>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_wrapper' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_container'/>
    </row>
    <column exact='1' name='col1' attr='text'>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_wrapper' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_container'/>
        <webctrl tag='a' class='pdp_link' idx='1'/>
    </column>
    <column exact='1' name='Column2' attr='text'>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_wrapper' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_container'/>
        <webctrl tag='a' class='pdp_link' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_details_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='title_wrapper' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='title' idx='1'/>
    </column>
    <column exact='1' name='Column3' attr='text'>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='shelf_wrapper' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_container'/>
        <webctrl tag='a' class='pdp_link' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_details_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='price_container' idx='1'/>
        <webctrl tag='div' class='product_price' idx='1'/>
    </column>
</extract>
```